# How i can extract data

Tags: array, post-meta

Hello i have form with nested repeater field, all data in nested repeater group saving in database like this: `a:6:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:21:"Initial ";s:11:"description";s:78:"Please show identify.";}}`

in database all ok, but how i can get title value, description value, when i try `get via get_post_meta`, for example:
`get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'part_0_module[0][title],  true )` - nothing, `part_0_module[0][title]` - this my field name.

Can you help me solve this problem and get data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to access data.

For example:

```
<?php
$data = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'field_name', true );
$data = unserialize($data);

// Print the data
print_r($data);
```

Comment: `get_post_meta();` Should handle unserializing.